# Customize HTML5 Video Stop Point / Frame

Tags: html, video

When embedding a normal HTML5 video; the video will stop and remain idle at the last frame of the video. I'd like the video to stop; and display not the first frame, but maybe a second past. Is this possible? EG. After it played once; it stops on the first actual frame (Not the black)

Basically; I'm creating buttons; each button will display an HTML5 video I have set to autoplay; from there I wanted the button that was previously clicked to show the first actual frame of the html5 video; once it's already played. I'm thinking 1 second past the start should do it; as it displays the first 'area or frame' as black.

How can I customize where the freeze frame is after a video has already played with autoplay in HTML5.

**Edit://**

**I've just tried below and no such luck;**

```
<script>

video.onended = function(e) {
/*Do things here?*/

{
    video.currentTime = 3.0;
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Media API to listen for the `ended` event, once this has been fired, then set the video's `currentTime` to whatever value you want (e.g. 1 second).

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
video.addEventListener('ended', function() { 
   this.currentTime = 1; 
}, false);
```

Where `video` is a handle to your video element.

Comment: Thanks, what is / how do I use Media API? Link; or how could I write this?